# Using built-in libxml2 on Mac 10.6.x

Tags: python, macos, osx-snow-leopard, libxml2

I understand that Mac OS 10.6.x contains a built-in version of libxml2.

I feel pretty stupid here, but then why doesn't this work?

```
python -c "import libxml2"
```

Is there some step I'm missing that makes the library accessible in Python?

```
which python
```

...returns:

```
/usr/bin/python2.6 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6
```

... so it looks to me like I'm using the default python.

I was able to find lots of older instructions for installing new versions of libxml2 on older versions of Mac OS, but nothing about just using what it comes with on 10.6.x. I prefer to use the built-in stuff instead of MacPorts if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a post that explains how to install libxml2 for python on OS X: http://lsimons.wordpress.com/2008/08/31/how-to-install-lxml-python-module-on-mac-os-105-leopard/

Comment: Based on your answer and the one above, I tried to follow the directions in the comment of this post - get the sourcecode, run setup.py install. That seems to put a bunch of files into /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages (folder did not exist before). Afterwards, `python -c "import libxml2"` still returns an error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "libxml2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import libxml2mod
ImportError: No module named libxml2mod`

Answer (score 0):

You almost certainly have libxml2 -- which comes with the OS -- but you're likely missing the Python bindings, which don't seem to. That would be a shared library named something like "libxml2mod.so" inside the /Library/Python or /Library/Frameworks/Python trees. I don't think there's any way to avoid installing something, MacPorts being one fine way to do so. You can use the inbuilt libxml2, though, and just install the bindings.